# Print folder contents with non-standard printing settings

Tags: applescript, automator, printing, script

I want to print all files which are dragged to a folder. Easy to do with Automator.

But I want to specify more settings for the print, namely to print the items two times, to use paper tray 2 instead of 1 (standard); the file should be deleted afterwards (This would also be easy with Automator)

Is there a way to specify these special options? The process is all the time the same, so there should be no promt to ask me what options I want to choose; it should be a simple workflow: Drag files on folder, print with these settings.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lemme see if I can do this...

Comment: Investigating a bit, I must admit I shortchanged you on my answer. `lp` / `lpr` are one way to achieve what you asked for, there is at least one other (mucking with the last set printer preset via `defaults` or Applescript). Pulling my answer, as it is correct as to the limitations of plain AppleScript / Automator, but not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to do this in Automator.  My work around was as follows:

- Use Automator to convert all documents to pdf
- use [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html) to print from the terminal with non-standard settings, e.g.

  $ for i in *pdf; do lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge $i; done